# Partial page update ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

In controller, method associated with page recieves ViewData from other part of the programme and displays the View like this

```
public IActionResult Index() {
            ViewData["msg"] = Client.GetMessage();
            return View();
        }
```

How can I update page only partially if ViewData I need to display changed?

Comment: Are you asking for general instructions on how to build a [partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148463/how-to-use-partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc)? That is a very broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Though you didn't show the complete picture but from here I can suggest you to go for conditional razor syntax in your html.

For example:

```
<div>
  @if(msg.Length>10){
     <p>Too big message.</p>
  } 
  else {
     <p>@msg</p>
  } 
</div>
```